# String Manipulation in Embedded Ruby

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

So I have embedded Ruby in HTML, and I need to declare a new variable which will be a manipulated version of the old variable. For instance, in

```
<%= newfood = food%>
```

if food = "AB&CSoup", I'd want the string to become "ABCSoup". After declaring the new variable in embedded ruby brackets, how can I remove the ampersand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% newfood = food %>
<% newfood.gsub!('&','') %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [delete](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-delete) method

```
<%= newfood = food.delete('&') %>
```